# Looking for "get foot in the door" small contract ideas for finding web design and IT services clients

Tags: freelance-websites, web-development, webmasters

Times are tough and finding clients for a full website is getting tougher, so I'm looking for parallel services I could offer to get my foot in the door, small mini contracts to help make their websites better.

Just like a garage might offer discounted oil changes, then they can upgrade to tune up and put more parts on.

Any ideas or suggestions? Please post you list of services that could be offered?

Comment: Impossible. Nobody would give you free lunch. Finding works is always hard.

Comment: You realize you are somewhat asking your competition for their marketing secrets, right?

Comment: Yes, but I'm in Thailand, I doubt I will step on the turf of local guys around the world...;) I would give "some" tips to someone who asks as long as they don't directly compete with me. Isn't that what all these help forums are all about? Open source? Getting power with sharing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how "we" would offer a list of services that you can do. We don't know your skillset.  If I said list yourself as a Java developer and you are not a Java guy then what good would that do? What are your webdev skills?

Comment: I mean like business card design, flyers, brochures, reformat windows etc...

Comment: Put up a website, create some designs from start to finish and use some freelancer sites. Until you show someone  what you can do, it will be difficult to get any work.  What does "reformat windows" mean?  And what software are you proficient at for design?